# Symbolic calculator in Python: how to correctly override __eq__

Tags: python, oop

I've written a small symbolic calculator in Python to represent the real numbers.

```
class Symbol:
    def __init__(self, name, negated=False):
        self.name = name
        self.negated = negated

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Symbol):
            print("what do I do?")

        return self.name == other.name and \
               self.negated == other.negated

    def __neg__(self):
        return Symbol(self.name, not self.negated)

    def __pos__(self):
        return Symbol(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return "-" + self.name if self.negated else self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


class Add:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left; self.right = right

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Add):
            print("what do I do?")

        return (self.left  == other.left and self.right == other.right) or\
               (self.right == other.left and self.left  == other.right)

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s + %s)" %(self.left, self.right)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

a = Symbol("a")
b = Symbol("b")
c = Symbol("c")

print(Add(a, b) == Add(b, a)) #commutativity 
print(Add(a, Add(b, c)) == Add(Add(a, b), c)) #associativity
```

When Python goes to check equality in the second `print` statement, it will compare `a` with `Add(a, b)`. These are different types; how should I override the `__eq__` method to correctly support the [associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)?

Comment: Btw, you have mistake in your logic. Because in second print you should compare result of `Add(a, Add(b, c))` with result of `(Add(Add(a, b), c)`. So, before final step it should be `a, b, c` vs `a, b, c`.

Comment: I'm not seeing the mistake -- what do you think the code in the second print statement should be?

Comment: No, you are right. There is no mistake. I just thought that `Add` will calculate something. But it's just a storage :)

Comment: Yes -- this just does math in symbols, not with numeric values.

Comment: Can you add a link to some article how it should work?

Comment: I'm trying to support [these operations](http://www.openbookproject.net/books/finitemath/app_c.html) on the set of real numbers in the abstract (i.e. using symbols). The second test illustrates the associative property, which is currently failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90562/discussion-between-jimilian-and-rookie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
def __eq__(self, other)
    th = str(self)
    th = th.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(" ","")
    ot = str(other).replace("(","")
    ot = ot.replace(")","").replace(" ","")
    return sorted(th.split("+")) == sorted(ot.split("+"))
```

I don't know if this is the best.

EDIT:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, l, r):
    self.l = l
    self.r = r
  def __str__(self):
    return "(%s + %s)" %(self.l, self.r)
  def __eq__(self, other):
    th = str(self).replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(" ","")
    ot = str(other).replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(" ","")
    return sorted(th.split('+')) == sorted(ot.split('+'))
```

`A('a',A('b','c')) == A('b',A('a','c'))` gave me `True`

Comment: I was hoping there might be a more oop solution (I don't know if there is). Thank you for your answer.